# How to make the URL different from the path of the php file (Nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, url, path

I was wondering how I can make the URL of my website different from the path of the file in my website directory.

For example, let's say I want my website language to be in the URL (mywebsite/en/index.php) but I don't want to manually have to create each php file in my website directory containing just an include from my main files, how could I do that please? I'm using Nginx if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nginx rewrite regex rules.
[Nginx rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Let's say you want the url below to hit index.php with the language code.

```sh
Url: https://yourwebsite.com/en/index.php
FilePath: /path/to/www/index.php
```

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/index.php$ /index.php?lang=$1 last;

# another example
# $1 is the matching characters in regex `(.*)`
rewrite ^/sales/(.*)/categories.php$ /some/path/cat.php?categories=$1 last;
```

Do not forget. All URL's are imaginary but all files are real. URLs do not need to match the real files.
URL: `https://yourwebsite.com/index.php` may hit `/some.file.asp`

Look at the official nginx documentation for more details.

Hope, it helps.